# Network unreachable after docker install on raspberry pi 4 raspian buster

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

**Problem:**
I have previously had netwworking working via ethernet and wireless on my raspberry pi4.

I installed Docker and built the reporptportal images from   curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reportportal/reportportal/master/docker-compose.yml -o docker-compose.yml. This install completed successfully but some images have issues and after a reboot I now don't have internet access.

I was expecting that the docker-compose uses a default isolated network which I understand is default behaviour, but perhaps this is not true or there is some other configuration step I am missing.
I'm not a networking expert so am a bit stuck on this.

Here is the output from:

**traceroute 4.4.4.4**

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
connect: Network is unreachable
```

**ip link**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:04:2a:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:04:2a:9d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:fb:5c:18:31 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br-97a0c2dc3c6b: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:f6:24:06:50 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
21: veth0d17bc0@if20: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-97a0c2dc3c6b state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether e6:a5:76:1f:2a:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 10
23: vethf4fa3c3@if22: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-97a0c2dc3c6b state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether be:54:91:32:d6:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 5
27: veth05f2b7e@if26: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-97a0c2dc3c6b state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether f6:80:67:18:6e:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 7
845: vethfcc425d@if844: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-97a0c2dc3c6b state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 8a:bc:ad:0e:ed:67 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
```

**ifconfig**

> br-97a0c2dc3c6b: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>           inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
>           inet6 fe80::42:f6ff:fe24:650  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>           ether 02:42:f6:24:06:50  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 56  bytes 7101 (6.9 KiB)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 51  bytes 6760 (6.6 KiB)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> docker0: flags=4099  mtu 1500
>           inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
>           ether 02:42:fb:5c:18:31  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> eth0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>           inet6 fe80::48ed:6e6d:f46e:4dea  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>           ether dc:a6:32:04:2a:9c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 428  bytes 38739 (37.8 KiB)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 12  bytes 1520 (1.4 KiB)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
>           inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
>           inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
>           loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
>           RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> veth05f2b7e: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>           inet6 fe80::f480:67ff:fe18:6e96  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>           ether f6:80:67:18:6e:96  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 10  bytes 700 (700.0 B)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 48  bytes 5670 (5.5 KiB)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> veth0d17bc0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>           inet6 fe80::7c1e:a1e4:8760:b726  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>           inet6 fe80::e4a5:76ff:fe1f:2a40  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>           ether e6:a5:76:1f:2a:40  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 86  bytes 12948 (12.6 KiB)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> vethf4fa3c3: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>           inet6 fe80::6273:fa3f:d659:8bc1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>           inet6 fe80::bc54:91ff:fe32:d634  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>           ether be:54:91:32:d6:34  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 73  bytes 11189 (10.9 KiB)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Can someon please help me fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems by default Docker uses the local network and I think moves all network devices to IP6 only,

This seems to be the default behaviour if you don't define a network and set all service to use it.

Chaning the docker-compose file to include:
networks:
YOURNETWORKNAME:

and nest under each service:
networks:
- YOURNETWORKNAME

...gave me back ip4 connectivity.

Comment: Thank got I found your comment. I don't understand what YOURNETWORKNAME should be here, I have made the workaround of stopping all containers and rebooting. If it's on ethernet, should it be eth0?

Comment: @Jano  YOURNETWORKNAME is simply your custom name for a 'custom' docker defined network. See Specify custom networks see https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/. You also need to state for each docker service that they should be 'joined' to this custom network so need to add the relevent eg. networks: JanosCustomNetworkName